# Constructor Injection (Dependency Injection) in a class (NOT Controller Class) in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I am struggling to understand how I can utilize dependency injection in this scenario.

Let me introduce my files one by one.

A contract called ITxtManipulator.cs

```
public interface ITxtManipulator
{
    public string StringCapitalize(string incoming_string);
}
```

A class called TxtManipulatorA.cs
This implements the ITxtManipulator interface

```
public class TxtManipulatorA : ITxtManipulator
{
    public string StringCapitalize(string incoming_string)
    {
        return incoming_string.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

This is program.cs where I registered dependency injection

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITxtManipulator, TxtManipulatorA>();   // <------- HERE

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

I have an application layer. I created a class called SomeApplication.cs
This is where I want to invoke ITxtManipulator object and use it a method.
I tried to use Constructor Injection.

```
public class SomeApplication
{
    private readonly ITxtManipulator _magicTxtManipulator;
    
    public SomeApplication(ITxtManipulator dotnetGiveTxtManipulator)
    {
        _magicTxtManipulator = dotnetGiveTxtManipulator;
    }

    public string GetStudentDefault()
    {
        return _magicTxtManipulator.StringCapitalize("raj");
    }
}
```

Finally I want to invoke method 'GetStudentDefault()' in the StudentController.cs.
This is where I am stuck and getting error.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return new SomeApplication().GetStudentDefault();  // <--- COMPILE ERROR
    }
}
```

Giving me error! (I couldn't execute the code itself)  Since the constructor of SomeApplication expects an argument (ITxtManipulator) which I cannot pass and dotnet has to provide.

I **do not** want to use dependency injection in **the controller class**.

I want to do dependency injection in Application Layer (SomeApplication.cs) and then invoke the method in the controller class to achieve separation of concerns.

Can someone suggest a way to leverage dependency injection and satisfy my architectural requirement in this scenario?

Comment: You are not telling what the actual error is.

Comment: Injecting the `SomeApplication` into the controller's constructor is is the most common practice, which can be seen if you read Microsoft's documentation on Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core. Can you, therefore, explain why you "do not want to use dependency injection in the controller class?" What are your architectural requirements concerning this and what are their purpose?

Comment: "I want to do dependency injection in Application Layer (SomeApplication.cs) and then invoke the method in the controller class to achieve separation of concerns." The way you try to do it violates separation of concerns. Your controller class shouldn't be concerned with building a `SomeApplication` instance (the `new SomeApplication()` in your code). You will achieve separation of concerns if your controller class accepts a `SomeApplication` in its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually calling the constructor from a Controller. This means you can inject the `ITxtManipulator` in the Controller's constructor, set a field with that value and add it to the constructor parameters of `SomeApplication`.
Your `StudentController` class would then look like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private ITxtManipulator _manipulator;
    public StudentController(ITxtManipulator manipulator) 
    {
        _manipulator = manipulator;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return new SomeApplication(_manipulator).GetStudentDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: @RajkumarVadla You're welcome! Lots of luck with your project!